# Deployment with replicas and resources not deploying specific resources in Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I tried to add Deployment with replicas in Azure. I added resources but it's always taking 4 CPU and 15Gi Memory.
Below is the deployed yml.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test-cf-ns
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-cf
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-cf
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      containers:
      - image: adobecoldfusion/coldfusion2021:latest
        name: test-cf
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 8Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 8Gi
```

Comment: Can you kindly expand your problem little bit more ? So from the YAML file I see that you have specified limits , If you have deployed that particular YAML - it should take only that limits.
Can you see the deployed YAML ? Kubectl get deploy test -n test-cf-ns -o yaml

From where do you see that it is still taking 4 CPU & 15 GiB

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you provided sets the request and limit for CPU and memory to the same values, which means that each pod in your deployment is allocated a fixed number of resources i.e. (2 CPUs and 8Gi memory). However, the total resources for the deployment i.e. replicas per-pod would be 6 CPUs and 24Gi memory, not 4 CPUs and 15Gi memory as you mentioned. If you want to limit each pod to use a maximum of 2 CPUs and 8Gi memory

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test-cf-ns
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-cf
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-cf
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      containers:
      - image: adobecoldfusion/coldfusion2021:latest
        name: test-cf
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 8Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 2Gi
```

[image]

With the above yaml config each pod is guaranteed to get at least 0.5 CPU and 2Gi memory requests but can use up to 2 CPUs and 8Gi memory limits if available.

Now when you do

```
 kubectl get deploy test -n test-cf-ns -o yaml
```

You will see that based on the specified limits, it should take only those limits as you can see in the below **output-**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"test","namespace":"test-cf-ns"},"spec":{"replicas":3,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"test-cf"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"test-cf"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"image":"adobecoldfusion/coldfusion2021:latest","imagePullPolicy":"Always","name":"test-cf","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":2,"memory":"8Gi"},"requests":{"cpu":0.5,"memory":"2Gi"}}}],"nodeSelector":{"kubernetes.io/os":"linux"}}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-11-16T09:38:49Z"
  generation: 1
  name: test
  namespace: test-cf-ns
  resourceVersion: "52482"
  uid: 02a33b76-ce21-4132-aec3-8b161db8ea51
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-cf
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: test-cf
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: adobecoldfusion/coldfusion2021:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: test-cf
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 8Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 2Gi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
```